# Creating an *int in C++ - What is the point of MSVC's extra store/reload of a function return value before assigning it to a global?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I am a beginner to assembly code. When developing in C++, I noticed some assembly code generated by the MSVC that I don't understand. The code in question is:

```
00DA1965  push        4 // The number of bytes we want
00DA1967  call        operator new (0DA1339h) // Call to 'new' to allocate memory
00DA196C  add         esp,4 // Add the 4 bytes to the stack pointer
00DA196F  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0D4h],eax // Move the return address from EAX into a temporary variable?
00DA1975  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0D4h] // Move it back into EAX?
00DA197B  mov         dword ptr [age],eax // And then into my variable?
```

The corresponding C++ code:

```
int *age = new int;
```

If I understand it correctly, we move the value in EAX to a temporary variable at EBP-0D4h. And in the next instruction we then move it back to where it was.

What is the point of this? (00DA196F and 00DA1975)

Comment: I would guess that the code is built with the optimiser off, so that's just what happens when you turn it off. [Godbolt with `/O0`](https://godbolt.org/z/NcHUzd) and [Godbolt with `/O1`](https://godbolt.org/z/FiF5h5)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking questions related to unoptimized code is pointless.

Comment: Just unoptimized code.

Answer (score 3):

MSVC's anti-optimized debug build asm output is usually even more braindead than gcc or clang's anti-optimized builds.

**There's no sane reason to spill/reload the return value to the stack even in a debug build**: the temporary isn't accessible via any name in the C++ abstract machine, and there's no debug info that lets you see it between the end of `new` and the update of `p`.

**`int*` is a trivially-copyable type, so there's no copy-constructor to run when copying the return value to a local.  But presumably that's why MSVC is doing it.**

---

gcc doesn't do that inside a function or in the static initializer function if you put that `new` at global scope.  https://godbolt.org/z/51SM3N

**If you don't want to look at stupid braindead asm, compile with optimization enabled**, like `-O2` or `-Ox` in MSVC.  Then you get the expected static initializer:

```
;;; x86 MSVC -O2 output
??__Ep@@YAXXZ PROC                                  ; ??__Ep@@YAXXZ, COMDAT
    push    4
    call    void * operator new(unsigned int)                            ; operator new
    add     esp, 4
    mov     DWORD PTR int * p, eax      ; p
    ret     0
```

Or for x86-64,

```
?__Ep@@YAXXZ PROC                                  ; ??__Ep@@YAXXZ, COMDAT
    sub     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
    mov     ecx, 4
    call    void * __ptr64 operator new(unsigned __int64)                      ; operator new
    mov     QWORD PTR int * __ptr64 __ptr64 p, rax                ; p
    add     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
    ret     0
```

Answer (score 0):

MSVC is splitting up the line of code:

```
int *age = new int;
```

into two steps:

```
                                                ;1st step
        push        4                           ;temp var = new int
        call        operator new
        add         esp,4
        mov         dword ptr [ebp-0D4h],eax
                                                ;2nd step    
        mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0D4h]    ;int *age = temp var
        mov         dword ptr [age],eax
```